# can you align items in a marquee tag html? in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to put images inside a marquee tool but whenever I do display flex and align items center it doesn't allow me to and the items don't get any effect done.

[image]

Can you apply any styling to a marquee tool? Such as flex? If not, how can you align items so that it gets centred?

Here is my HTML code in React:

```
  <marquee  scrolldelay="-10" direction="right" style={{display:"flex", alignItems:"center"}}>
            <img src={ReactIcon} style={{marginRight:"50px"}}/> 
            <img src={PHPIcon} style={{marginRight:"50px"}}/>
            <img src={MongoDB} style={{marginRight:"50px"}}/>
    </marquee>
```

Comment: Marquee tag has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). You shouldn't be using it

Answer (score 0):

## Marquee Polyfill

Marquee elements are deprecated, meaning that browsers no longer support them. Any bugs with the `<marquee>` tag will not be fixed, and new HTML standards will not be compatible with that tag. Additionally, the feature will soon be completely removed from web browsers.

What you are actually looking for is a polyfill – a set of code which mimicks the `<marquee>` functionality. Luckily, this polyfill is very easy to create yourself using CSS animations.

### CodePen Live Example

To checkout a live example (and the code) for this polyfill, I quickly created a demo on codepen:

https://codepen.io/virajshah21/pen/VwQQRmd

### HTML

```html
<div class="marquee-outer">
  <div class="marquee-inner">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

You can replace the content inside of `.marquee-inner` with whatever you want, just do not remove `.marquee-inner` or change its styles.

- `.marquee-outer` is the box which contains the marquee
- `.marquee-inner` is the element that is shifted

> You can add your own `div` and style it using flex-boxes, or however else you would like

### CSS

```css
.marquee-outer {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee-inner {
  animation-name: marquee;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

### I will break this down for you

```css
.marquee-outer {
  width: 100%; /* Stretches the marquee container */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Prevents padding overflow */
  padding: 0.5rem; /* Adds some padding so your marquee looks nice */
  background: rgb(240, 240, 240); /* Change the background */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hides the text when it is not in the element */
}
```

---

```css
.marquee-inner {
  animation-name: marquee; /* Uses the defined marquee keyframe */
  animation-duration: 10s; /* Makes the animation take 10 seconds */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Replays the animation after its done */
  animation-timing-function: linear; /* Keeps the animation moving at the same speed */
  position: relative; /* Allows the marquee content to be shifted */
}
```

---

```css
/* Defines a keyframe animation named "marquee" */
@keyframes marquee {
  /* The content starts off shifted all the way to the right */
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Then the content shifts all the way to the left */
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

Comment: but this way it stops at the end, I want it to go all the way through

Comment: You can modify the keyframes. Change `left: 0%` to `left: -100%`. This will make it so that if you have content that takes up all the space of the marquee then it will all disappear before restarting the animation.